# Equipotential Contour mapping and making it 3D

Tags: electricity, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

I have seen Contour diagrams for Equipotentials . That are drawn like so:

http://puu.sh/tda8

I also saw One image for these contours that was in 3D (Negative Point Charge) :

[image]

I was Wondering If there's any equation that represents these Contours In 3D?

Because I wanted to recreate these `3D` Contour On `Mathematica`. I Know A little about 3d functions but not much.

But I do Know that this 3D Function  Looks A bit like the function

> $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$$
> http://puu.sh/tdgS
> and $$f(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2}$$
> http://puu.sh/tdhs
> But I couldn't get it to taper at the tip.

Could Anyone tell me how it could be made into 3d or how i could make it taper into a pointed tip at the top/bottom.

BTW:{It Also resembles the [physics.stackexchange.com](http://physics.stackexchange.com) Logo but isn't differentiable at the top}

I tried to make it 3D using the same equation but i got something like :

> http://puu.sh/tdiQ
>
> > For this $$f(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}$$ I got:
> > http://puu.sh/tdpn
> > but it isnt as steep as the countour i wanted.

Comment: Migration of software part of the question to mathematica.SE?

Comment: i just want the equation that would give me the required plot.

Comment: Well you can easily change range of your plots in Mathematica, have you tried with that?

Comment: @Qmechanic  NO..... maybe its $\frac{kQ}{x^2+y^2}$ dingo_d the range of my function is infinity i want the function to change a bit so that it tapers more steeply and makes a point fairly earlier than infinity

Comment: This seems to be a question about how to reproduce the desired plot in Mathematica, rather than a plot about making electric equipotential lines (which you've shown you're able to do), so I'll see if the Mathematica mods want it.

Comment: Update: the question is not suitable for migration as is, but you could ask it anew on [mathematica.SE]. Make sure to write the question so that it is appropriate for that site; don't just blindly copy and paste what you've written here.

Comment: Apologies, my script didn't notice the URLs were used for other screenshots in the meantime. I couldn't find the original images in the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plot you're trying to imitate seems to not go to infinity. I'd suggest you play around with potentials of the form $$V=\frac{V_0}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+\delta^2}}.$$

E.g. Something like

```
Plot3D[-(1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + \[Delta]^2]) /. {\[Delta] -> 1/10}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,
1}, PlotRange -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

gives[image]

Comment: This looks right, you can change the z range so it will look more 'steeper':
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, -20}}
You can also change opacity and play with Mesh to get circles.